# Dirac-like formulation of quantum electrodynamics

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, quantum-interpretations

For classical mechanics there is a newtonian formulation (calculating accelerations and integrating to get velocities and positions). There is also an equivalent Lagrangian formulation (finding a path that minimizes the action).

In quantum mechanics instead of the "newtonian formulation" we have the time-dependent Schrodinger equation, which is similar to the classical wave and heat equations. The Lagrangian formulation gets modified to handle [multiple paths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_integral_formulation).

But in quantum field theory I can only find the Lagrangian-like formulation. Is there some sort of a "Dirac" formulation, where the electron/positron field propagates according to the Dirac equation and the photon field according to Maxwell equations? Interaction terms would allow creating fields, and fields propagating to infinity would give cross-sections.